# Network payload is less in RF when entity proxies are used. But how to validate it?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

My basic question in one line is: 
**How to validate that only diff is sent across the browser in RequestFactory?**

Am stuck with that. Hope I can get it resolved.

Description:

I wrote a sample application that uses request factory and was trying to find out what difference it makes in the data that is sent over the wire. My sample screen looks like this:

[image: GUI screen]

Am purposefully appending the address string with a huge string and able to get a payload in KBs for the first time. But when I try to update that entity again without changing that big string, diff is calculated and that string is not shown in the `P` element in Network but the data size remains the same to the previous request. I have attached those pics as well. What am in missing here?

[image: Look at address string set really long]

Why is network data in chrome showing the same value as before even though the big string is not sent in the next request?

I have tried my best to explain here. Kindly ask me if anything is unclear. Thanks a lot.

I could not upload image as some issue was preventing me from uploading image. I have added the payload information of the two requests here.

**An entity getting saved:-**

```
F: "com.first.shared.ExampleApplicationRequestFactory"
I: [{P:[{T:SthgDWKGDyVU7XY2_BerXnH$ujE=, R:1, C:1}], R:[*.*], O:Gmm2HER5ETasZhvmQq72gtmtEz0=}]
O: [{T:SthgDWKGDyVU7XY2_BerXnH$ujE=, P:{,…}, C:1, R:1, O:PERSIST},…]
0: {T:SthgDWKGDyVU7XY2_BerXnH$ujE=, P:{,…}, C:1, R:1, O:PERSIST}
C: 1
O: "PERSIST"
P: {,…}
address: {T:r3GDJrFpjlkGiv5IxQq56QaH0oQ=, R:1, C:2}
detail: {T:c2QMWXl3jRvuopMBwuBwIIjIBRc=, R:1, C:3}
firstName: "lpd"
lastName: "detail example detail example detail example detail example detail example detail example detail example detail example detail example detail example detail example detail example detail example .... [and so on]"
R: "1"
T: "SthgDWKGDyVU7XY2_BerXnH$ujE="
1: {T:r3GDJrFpjlkGiv5IxQq56QaH0oQ=, P:{city:Bangalore}, C:2, R:1, O:PERSIST}
C: 2
O: "PERSIST"
P: {city:Bangalore}
R: "1"
T: "r3GDJrFpjlkGiv5IxQq56QaH0oQ="
2: {T:c2QMWXl3jRvuopMBwuBwIIjIBRc=, P:{detail:India}, C:3, R:1, O:PERSIST}
Response Headersview source
```

**Same entity getting updated:-**

```
F: "com.first.shared.ExampleApplicationRequestFactory"
I: [{P:[{T:SthgDWKGDyVU7XY2_BerXnH$ujE=, S:IjIi}], R:[*.*], O:Gmm2HER5ETasZhvmQq72gtmtEz0=}]
O: [{T:SthgDWKGDyVU7XY2_BerXnH$ujE=, V:MS4w, P:{firstName:lpd-2}, S:IjIi, O:UPDATE},…]
0: {T:SthgDWKGDyVU7XY2_BerXnH$ujE=, V:MS4w, P:{firstName:lpd-2}, S:IjIi, O:UPDATE}
O: "UPDATE"
P: {firstName:lpd-2}
firstName: "lpd-2"
S: "IjIi"
T: "SthgDWKGDyVU7XY2_BerXnH$ujE="
V: "MS4w"
1: {T:r3GDJrFpjlkGiv5IxQq56QaH0oQ=, V:MS4w, S:IjIi, O:UPDATE}
2: {T:c2QMWXl3jRvuopMBwuBwIIjIBRc=, V:MS4w, S:IjIi, O:UPDATE}
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us the payload of the requests? BTW, the _size_ showed in the screenshot is the _response_ size, not the _request_ size.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies sir. I have added pay load information data in two cases, where first one is a fresh entity saved and second one is the update operation. I see that only diff is sent in the second case, but am not able to understand how to quantify the savings here.

Comment: If you want to _quantify_ things, look at the `Content-Length` **request** header in the _Headers_ tab when you click on a specific request/response in the Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped. I was looking at the wrong place and was getting confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved based on the imputs that were provided by Thomas Broyer.

If you want to quantify things, look at the Content-Length request header in the Headers tab when you click on a specific request/response in the Chrome Dev Tools. – Thomas Broyer